# How to mock/pass a Nodejs helper utility which executes functions in it using mocha-chai-sinon

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

Let's say I have a file like below:

src/blah.js

```
var Foo = require("../../something/foo.js");

var goo = new Foo({
  host: argv.host.toString(),
  port: parseInt(argv.port)
});
goo.order("service_name");
goo.do("invalidPhone", function(req, done) {
  goo.talk('newFunc', 'newAct', req.data, function(newActErr, newActResponse){
       done(newActResponse)
  })
});

exports.goo = goo;
```

Where "something/foo.js" is utility helper project that does various functions. 
Let's say `goo.order` registers the service_name somewhere and `goo.do` actually performs some work using `invalidPhone` as a function name.

In this case, some other service calls on the `invalidPhone` function with some parameter `req`. When `invalidPhone` function gets called, the function is supposed to print "Here!" along with whatever comes in `req.data`.

Is there anyway for me to write a unit test case for `invalidPhone` function? I assume to achieve that I need to somehow mock `goo.do()`, but how do I do that?

I tried writing a test case as below:

```
var eventService = require("../src/blah");
var base = eventService.goo;
var sinon = require("sinon");

describe("Goo Blah service", function(done) {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.consoleSpy = sinon.spy(console, "log");
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    this.consoleSpy.restore();
  });

  it("Response should be logged", function() {
    goo.action("invalidPhone", "a123456789");
    this.consoleSpy.called.should.be.true;
  });
});
```

But the above doesn't seem to work.

EDIT 1: What if my code looks like below, and I have a new function `goo.talk` to mock/stub and return some values in `newActErr` and `newActResp`? The values `newFunc` and `newAct` can change. How do I do that then?

```
var Foo = require("../../something/foo.js");

var goo = new Foo({
  host: argv.host.toString(),
  port: parseInt(argv.port)
});
goo.order("service_name");
goo.do("invalidPhone", function(req, done) {
  goo.talk('newFunc', 'newAct', req.data, function(newActErr, newActResponse){
       if(newActResponse.status){
          done(null, newActResponse)
       } else {
          done('error', null)
       }

  })
});

exports.goo = goo;
```

Going by the answer hint/help provided by deerawan, I tried the below:

```
talkStub = sinon.stub().withArgs('newFunc', 'newAct', {data: "name"}).returns({"status":"online"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test couldn't work because you mock/spy `console.log` after you load the source file `blah` at beginning of file

```
var eventService = require("../src/blah");
```

Beside that, it is also better if you can mock the `Foo` class so the test becomes isolated.

I suggest to use `proxyquire` to help do that stuff. `Proxyquire` works like `require` but also can do some mocking to any dependency in the source file.

Take a look at the solution below:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const sinon = require('sinon');

// need to specify this so Foo constructor can be initialized
process.argv.host = 'http';
process.argv.port = '333';

describe("Goo Blah service", function() {
  let consoleSpy;
  let orderStub;
  let doStub;

  beforeEach(function() {
    orderStub = sinon.stub();
    doStub = sinon.stub().yields({ data: 'mine' });

    // this our mock for Foo class
    function MockFoo() {
      return {
        order: orderStub,
        do: doStub,
      }  
    }

    consoleSpy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');

    // require the source file and mock `foo`
    proxyquire('../src/blah', { '../../something/foo.js': MockFoo } );
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    sinon.restore();
  });

  it("Response should be logged", function() {
    sinon.assert.calledWith(orderStub, 'service_name');
    sinon.assert.calledWith(doStub, 'invalidPhone');

    sinon.assert.called(consoleSpy);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(consoleSpy, 'Here!', 'mine');
  });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for this. I will definitely try to implement this and see if I can solve my problem with the ideas that you have provided.

Comment: I have a follow up question/doubt as shown in "Edit 1" in the main question. Can you please take a look at that and give me some thoughts?

Comment: @user1452759 you should use `yields` for `goo.talk` because it is callback function, so it becomes `talkStub = sinon.stub('newFunc', 'newAct', {data: "name"}).yields({"status":"online"})`

Comment: This is exactly what I first used, but I get this error, "TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property newAct as function"

Comment: oh sorry, my bad, I pasted wrong snippet. Yours is almost right but convert to `yields` e.g. `talkStub = sinon.stub().withArgs('newFunc', 'newAct', {data: "name"}).yields(null, {"status":"online"})`

Comment: Thank you! What about chaining/consecutive withArgs? 
For example : 
 goo.talk('newFunc', 'newAct', req.data, function(newActErr, nAResponse){
       if(nAResponse.status){
     goo.talk('f1', 'a2', newActResponse.status, function(errs, rep){
      done(null, rep)
     })
       } else {
          done('error', null)
       }
  })
I tried the below:
talkStub = sinon.stub().withArgs('newFunc', 'newAct', {data: "name"}).yields(null, {"status":"online"})
                               .withArgs('f1', 'a2', "online").yields(null, {"v": 5})
But it takes the last one.

Comment: @user1452759 you must create two stubs, before that, I created a stub variable `talkStub = sinon.stub()` then for the first stub `talkStub.withArgs('newFunc', 'newAct', {data: "name"}).yields(null, {"status":"online"})` and second one `talkStub.withArgs('f1', 'a2', "online").yields(null, {"v": 5})`

Comment: Oh my bad! That was stupid of me! I thought, "chaining" will work with the same stub. Thank you very much! You have been a big help!

Comment: @user1452759 glad it worked. Hope you get the idea :+1:

Comment: Any idea as to how to proxyquire  var a = require("yargs").argv? I have tried every possible thing for this, but it takes the original yargs and starts assigning values to it

Comment: Try this one `proxyquire('../src/blah', { 'yargs': { argv: 'my mock value' } );`

Comment: That was the first thing that I tried, but it doesn't work. I'm coming to the conclusion that yargs cannot be stubbed/mocked. So I had to pass the default values for the command line arguments that the file being tested needs.

Comment: @user1452759 hmm interesting. How about if we try using Sinon stub such as `proxyquire('../src/blah', { 'yargs': sinon.stub().returns({ argv: 'my mock value' } ));`?